# Navbar link margin classes seem repetitive in Tailwind CSS, is there a better way?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Having to add margin classes to each LI seems REALLY repetitive on a menu that is not being dynamically generated. This feels dirty like using style="" attributes...

Surely there must be a better way?

Not a huge deal on a small menu, but the final menu will have many levels of submenu.

I wonder if I should just write a rule in my stylesheet to add margins on my menu items?

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="p-2 bg-indigo-900 text-white">
    <ul class="flex flex-row">
        <li class="mr-1">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ml-1 mr-1">
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ml-1 mr-1">
            <a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ml-1 mr-1">
            <a href="#">History</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ml-1">
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I think in this case you will have to write your own rule to match all <li> elements from your unordered list, and then set specifics styles to first and last childs, like user9408899 said in the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with `tailwind-css` but you can make use of the `:last-child` and `:first-child` selectors.

```css
nav ul li {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="p-2 bg-indigo-900 text-white">
  <ul class="flex flex-row">
    <li class="">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="#">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="#">History</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I'm new to tailwind, but one of it's benefits is supposed to be preventing context-switching between html and css files.  I'll see if anyone with more TW experience chimes in before I settle on this.  Thanks!

Comment: Gotta say after redoing my interface in tailwind that I am not that impressed.  I constantly find myself asking why don't I just use <insert SASS feature> instead?  Partials seem really excessive for small components, and using @apply in my stylesheets seems really counter-intuitive.  For now, I'll stick with SASS and Bootstrap (atleast until Bulma adds utility classes out of the box)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to mark the answer above correct since I provided no context about this being a Laravel project.  What I have settled on is creating a partial for my nav, and then I pass it an array of labels and urls

```
// snippet of layouts/app.blade.php
@include('layouts._nav', ['links' => [
    [ 'label' => 'Main feed', 'url' => '/posts' ],
    [ 'label' => 'Announcements', 'url' => '/announcements' ],
    [ 'label' => 'Who to follow', 'url' => '/who-to-follow' ],
    [ 'label' => 'Profile', 'url' => '/profiles' ]
]])
```

```
// layouts/_nav.blade.php
<nav class="p-2 bg-indigo-900 text-white">
    <ul class="flex flex-row">
        @foreach($links as $link)
            @php
                if($loop->iteration === 1)
                    $class = 'mr-1';
                elseif($loop->iteration === $loop->count)
                    $class = 'ml-1';
                else
                    $class = 'ml-1 mr-1';
            @endphp
            <li class="{{ $class }}">
                <a href="{{ $link['url'] }}">{{ $link['label'] }}</a>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Output HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <ul class="flex flex-row">
        <li class="mr-1">
            <a href="/posts">Main feed</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ml-1 mr-1">
            <a href="/announcements">Announcements</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ml-1 mr-1">
            <a href="/who-to-follow">Who to follow</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ml-1">
            <a href="/profiles">Profile</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'first' and 'last' pseudo-classes to style those components. I think it is much easier than the other solutions. Something like this should work on React.js.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#first

```
<nav className="p-2 bg-indigo-900 text-white">
  <ul className="flex flex-row">
    {["Home", "About", "Services", "History", "Contact"].map(link=>{
      return (
        <li className="first:ml-10 last:mr-10">
          <a href="#">{link}</a>
        </li>
      )
    })
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32312301)

Comment: I've added some sample React for completeness